# Prevent SoX from doing the clipping?

Tags: audio, vlc, sox, libsox

I have a heavily "overflowed" WAV file (samples written in float 32-bit format): instead of [-1.0,+1.0], the samples range goes as far as [-5.0,+5.0].

Using [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html) to get raw PCM audio samples from WAV file:

`sox --bits 32 --channels 1 --encoding floating-point --rate 48000 input.wav output.raw`

I get warnings:

```
sox WARN sox: `input.wav' input clipped 1163400 samples
sox WARN sox: `output.raw' output clipped 605664 samples; decrease volume?
```

When I look into the output, I see the samples were clipped, and the range is [-1.0,+1.0] now. However, that is not what I want.

I would like to have exactly same output as input, just in different format (RAW instead of WAV). I need to use command line tool for the task. Is there a way to prevent SoX from doing the clipping?

Comment: looks like sox parm     gain -6  will lower amplitude by 6 dB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from the [SoX mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/sox/mailman/sox-users/).

The required behaviour isn't possible, however, in this specific case there is a workaround. Overriding input sample encoding as 32-bit **signed integer** instead of float, the values will be copied untouched; since the output is headerless, it doesn't matter what SoX thinks the samples are.

So, this works:
`sox --bits 32 --channels 1 --encoding signed-integer --rate 48000 input.wav output.raw`